# Rails Undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I already know there is a lot of `undefined method` questions, But I can't see whats wrong with mine so I need some help!

heres my form that i have

```
<% title("Home Page") %>
<h1><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Add Event <small>views/pages/home.html.erb</small></h1>
<div class="row">
  <%= simple_form_for Newevent.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :eventname, required: true %>
  <%= f.input :eventdesc %>
  <%= f.input :eventdate %>
  <%= f.input :eventimage %>
  <div class="col s6">
  <%= f.input :stubhublink %>
  <%= f.input :seatwavelink %>
  <%= f.input :viagogolink %>
</div>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I also have this in the controller

```
  def create
    create_params = params[:newevent].permit(:eventname, :eventdesc, :eventdate, :eventimage, :viagogolink, :seatwavelink, :stubhublink)
    @newevent = Newevent.new(create_params)
    byebug
    @newevent.save!
  end
```

and this in the model

```
class Newevent < ActiveRecord::Base

      def params
          params.require(:newevent).permit(:eventname, :eventdesc, :eventdate, :eventimage, :viagogolink, :seatwavelink, :stubhublink )
        end
    end
```

It was working fine with 3 (which were `eventname`, `eventdate` and `eventimage`) however after adding the other 4 in it now doesn't work. Any ideas?
Sorry heres the error!

```
NoMethodError in Newevents#new
Showing /Users/samroberts/Desktop/admitme/app/views/newevents/new.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `eventdesc` for #<Newevent:0x007fcaeee41f68>
```

Sam

Comment: It would be great if you could supply the error message

Comment: Not only would it be great, it's required. How are we supposed to spot where the error is? Oh wait I see the problem...

Comment: Sorry! Totally forgot haha!

Comment: It seems like you didn't have `eventdesc` field in your table. Please add new migration to add `eventdesc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems here buddy:

---

**1. `eventdesc` Missing**

The simple explanation for your error is that your `eventdesc` attribute is missing from your `NewEvent` model's table.

Since we don't have your table - or migrations - to observe, I'll have to give you a simple test:

```
  <%= simple_form_for Newevent.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :eventname, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :eventdesc %> #-> remove this line
    ...
```

Remove that, refresh the page and see if it works. If the error persists, it may mean another attribute is missing. If it disappears, it means this attribute is missing from your db, and as such you should use `rails g migration` to create a new one:

```
$ rails g migration AddEventDesc

#db/migrate/add_event_desc_xxxxxxxx.rb
class AddEventDesc
   def change
      add_column :new_events, :eventdesc, :string
   end
end
```

---

**2. Params**

Part of Rails 4's infrastructure is to use `strong params` to pass data from your controller to model.

As such, you need the following syntax:

```
#app/controllers/new_events_controller.rb
class NewEventsController < ApplicationController

   def new
      @newevent = NewEvent.new
   end

   def create
      @newevent = NewEvent.new new_event_params
      @newevent.save
   end

   private

   def new_event_params #-> you can call this whatever you like
          params.require(:newevent).permit(:eventname, :eventdesc, :eventdate, :eventimage, :viagogolink, :seatwavelink, :stubhublink )
   end
end
```

You need to keep your strong params function in your controller, not your model.

---

**3. Model Name**

Finally, this won't do much for you directly, but in the long run will help you massively; your model name.

Your model is `NewEvent`.

If this is what you *want* to call it, that is good. However, I have found the best way forward with model names is to keep them simple, preferably to one word.

I'd strongly recommend calling your model `Event`, so you can call `@event = Event.new` etc -- it just flows better.